# About pytorch the output is not what I expect

Tags: python, pytorch

```
import torch
a = torch.randn(2, 2)
a = ((a * 3) / (a - 1))
print(a)
```

The output is:

```
tensor([[  -0.7242,    2.0021],
        [-280.8320,    0.6750]])
```

But I think it should be:

```
tensor([[  6,    6],
        [  6,    6]])
```

Why I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`torch.randn` will preduce a random 2X2 tensor, as stated in the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.randn.html)

> Returns a tensor filled with random numbers from a normal distribution
> with mean 0 and variance 1 (also called the standard normal
> distribution).

In your case you will get the desired output if you will generate a tensor where all the values are 2.

```
a = torch.ones([2, 2], dtype=torch.float64) * 2.
```

will give you the desired one.

Answer (score 0):

`torch.randn(2,2)` generates a random normally distributed tensor of shape [2,2].
If you are expecting a definite value for a, try creating it as a numpy array and using `torch.Tensor(arr)`